# Store data with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I'm trying to store some data with `SharedPreferences`
method for store data:

```
    public void storeSharedPreferences(String string) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("DATA",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("FRAGMENT",string);
    editor.apply();

}
```

method for get data:

```
    public String getSharedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("DATA",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String string = sharedPreferences.getString("FRAGMENT","ONE");
    return string;
}
```

Method for fragment one and two:

```
 public void buttonSelect(String select) {
    if (select == "ONE") {
       storeSharedPreferences("ONE");


        fragment = new OneFragment();
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_process, fragment, "OneFragment").addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }
    if (select == "TWO") {

        storeSharedPreferences("TWO");

        fragment = new TwoFragment();
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_process, fragment, "TwoFragment").addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }
}
```

And i call This method at first

```
buttonSelect(getSharedPreferences());
```

Everything is works fine for example when the user is in fragment two and exit the app 
next time it will be start at fragment two
But the problem is use you close the app with menu(press menu button and clear all app) the next time you open the app nothing happen and seems this method never been called

```
buttonSelect(getSharedPreferences());
```

What can i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, use `editor.commit();` instead of `editor.apply();`

Next, the logic could be this:

1. When the app is launched for the first time, create a shared preference and save the last fragment flag as 0. This would mean that the user is at the home fragment.
2. Save the fragment number in the Shared Preferences whenever the user navigates through the app. SO this will keep on updating the last navigated fragment for the user.
3. Whenever the app is launched next time, it will have a shared preference with last fragment number, fetch the last navigated fragment from the Shared Preferences and pass it to your method `buttonSelect`
4. Your method `buttonSelect` will then load the specific fragment.

Note: Don't forget to call the method `buttonSelect` in the activity on app launch, either on `onCreate()` or on `onStart`
Oh I totally forgot, string comparison in Java should be done via string.equals() function rather than double equals

Comment: Can you explain why *editor.commit();* is preferred in this case and why not *editor.apply();*

Comment: You can read about the difference in apply() and commit() here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Comment: I am aware of the _ui thread_ and _asynchronous_ difference but my question was how did you debug that saving preferences asynchronously is the real issue in this code snippet.

Comment: I have seen such irregular instances where due to device or emulator issues, like free memory, disk read/write speed, the data gets updated in the SP but is not reflected. However, in this case, I haven't executed his code hence cannot guarantee about the same. It was just a suggestion to help him achieve his task. Also, if he wants, he can read about the difference between apply() and commit() over the link. What I focussed upon, was to give him an idea regarding the logic which I can think of, so that he try at his end, and achieve whatever he wants.

Comment: Oh I totally forgot, string comparison in Java should be done via string.equals function rather than double equals